# Using mono on an Ubuntu VPS (14.04.1 LTS), why is my HTTPS HttpListener never receiving a context?

Tags: c#, linux, https, mono, httplistener

I'm running a VPS with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS x64 installed. I have installed mono-complete. I am trying to create a simple HTTPS listener before I move on to bigger things. This is the first time I've ever done any development using Mono.

Below is the complete code for my test application:

```
namespace jvs
{
  using System;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.IO;

  class Host
  {
    public HttpListener Server { get; set; }
    public TextWriter Log { get; set; }

    public Host()
    {
      this.Server = null;
      this.Log = Console.Out;
    }

    public Host(TextWriter log)
    {
      this.Server = null;
      this.Log = log;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
      this.Server = new HttpListener();
      this.Server.Prefixes.Add("https://*:443/");
      this.Server.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
      this.Server.Start();
      this.Server.BeginGetContext(this.OnContextReceived, this.Server);
      Log.WriteLine("Host started; listening on:");
      foreach (var prefix in this.Server.Prefixes)
      {
        Log.WriteLine("  {0}", prefix.ToString());
      }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
      this.Server.Stop();
      this.Server = null;
    }

    private void OnContextReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
      // This function is NEVER called
      var server = ar.AsyncState as HttpListener;
      var context = this.Server.EndGetContext(ar);
      var identity = context.User.Identity as HttpListenerBasicIdentity;
      var response = context.Response;
      Log.WriteLine("Connection received");
      Log.WriteLine("  User: {0}\n  Password: {1}", identity.Name, identity.Password);
      server.BeginGetContext(this.OnContextReceived, server);
      using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
      using (var w = new StreamWriter(ms) { AutoFlush = true })
      {
        w.WriteLine(
        @"<html>
        <head>
        <title>Vorpalnet</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div style=""text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; height: 80%"">
        it worked.
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>");
        var buffer = ms.ToArray();
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        response.OutputStream.Close();
      }

    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Host host = new Host();
      host.Start();
      Console.Error.WriteLine("PID {0}", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
      while (true) { }
    }
  }
}
```

After compiling the code and running it (via `sudo` as to allow port 443 to be used), everything seems to be fine. However, when I open Firefox and navigate to the VPS address, I am given the message "The connection was interrupted."

Additionally, as stated in the comments, `OnContextReceived` is never called.

I have generated self-signed certificates for testing and configured them for use in the following manner:

```
$ makecert -r -n "CN=outpost" -sv outpost.pkv outpost.cer
$ httpcfg -add -port 443 -cert outpost.cer -pvk outpost.pvk
```

And to verify:

```
$ httpcfg -list
Port: 443 Thumbprint: 02F57058BB31783710E6836E5646601A5AEBEB48
$ ll ~/.config/.mono/httplistener
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 vps vps 4096 Sep 17 16:42 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 vps vps 4096 Sep 17 15:35 ../
-rw------- 1 vps vps  425 Sep 17 16:40 443.cer
-rw------- 1 vps vps  620 Sep 17 16:40 443.pvk
$ sudo ./host.exe
Host started; listening on:
  https://*:443/
PID 15961
```

While it was running, I opened up another session and ran `sudo netstat -antp | grep 443`; this is the output:

```
tcp    0     0 0.0.0.0:443         0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN      15961/cli
```

I attempted a connection to the host locally and got *nothing* in return, which makes me thing mono isn't picking up the certificate:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect outpost:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
2348096:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 318 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

I even enabled network trace logging via host.exe.config **which mono seems to ignore as NO output is written**:

```
$ cat host.exe.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Cache">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Http">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.HttpListener">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.WebSockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Http" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.HttpListener" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.WebSockets" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="network.log"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

It should be noted that **using plain HTTP ("http://*:80/") has *no* problems at all. Everything works.** Unfortunately, I will be needing HTTPS for the end goal of this project.

I've nearly pulled the remaining bits of hair out of my head at this point. Everything I've googled has solutions for this problem on Windows, but nothing useful on Linux.

Is this a mono configuration problem? Is there a step I'm missing? Did I generate the certificate wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was:

```
$ sudo httpcfg -add -port 443 -cert outpost.cer -pvk outpost.pvk
```

The reason: I was running `host.exe` via `sudo` to get permission to use port 443. As a result, the certificates were being pulled from `/root/.config/.mono/httplistener` instead of `/home/vps/.config/.mono/httplistener`. Running `httpcfg` via `sudo` put the certificates in the correct location.

What a headache for such a simple problem.